# Is "moreover/further/furthermore/besides/additionally" used together with "also" a redundancy?

Tags: redundancy

I read from [The Free Thesaurus](https://www.freethesaurus.com/moreover) that "moreover", "further", "furthermore", "besides", "additionally", as well as "also" are synonyms. So is using one of those words along with an "also" in a style exemplified as follows a redundancy?

> My hometown is a deplorable place for it is so urbanized a concrete jungle that even access to a tiny piece of the natural scene therein is desperate, and moreover, the cost of living therein is also so exorbitant that one usually has to have a very highly paid job to reach decent material condition.

Should either "moreover" or "also" be removed?

On the other hand, I see, in [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/moreover), an example:

> The university itself, moreover, is also unable to launch a serious
>   defence of the proposed centre.

Therein "moreover" and "also" are used together.

Therefore I wonder whether it is proper to use one of the enumerated words together with "also".

Comment: Your quoted sentence, to me, is unclear. The section, 'it is so urbanised a concrete jungle that even...', seems like a fragment was inserted in the sentence. Similarly, I think there is a missing article before 'decent material condition'.

Comment: @ifly6 I know that quote misses some pretexts, but as you can check from that link, all examples in that dictionary are that way, so you can only interpret them based on your imagination. Then, I don't know what you mean by "a fragment was inserted in the sentence"; I just use that section to elaborate why my hometown is a deplorable place. I actually just make a plain example, which is, nevertheless, real, of a style I often wish to use in my real writing, which is in scientific contexts.

Comment: @ifly6 I am not sure if an article should be placed prior to "condition" here. Before I posted, I had checked https://www.thefreedictionary.com/condition, wherein some examples use articles while some don't. If you can clearly tell me whether an article should be used in various kinds of situations, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Yes that would be redundant, whihc would be why you couldn't find any examples… and what happened when you tried, please?

"The university itself, moreover, is also unable…" is rather sloppy but if was perfect, it would still be nothing like saying "also moreover".

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The example I want is in a research paper, after several arguments are given, and finally you want to add something to supplement or emphasize the previous arguments. I haven't paid attention to this point in research papers, but next time if I find this structure, I will pay attention to it. As for the second example, in the comment following the answer to my question, Jason Bassford has given an example of the pretext wherein "...moreover ... also ..." isn't a redundancy.

Comment: Sorry, Captain Bohemian, and that's not actually so, any more than your "pretext" means anything like the "context" you seem to have been aiming at.

Jason Bassford gave a fine example of a context wherein many people wrongly fail to recognise "...moreover ... also ..." as a redundancy .

Do you see no difference?

Comment: Quite separately, how could it make any difference whether your example was in a research paper, or how many arguments were given?

Do you really think your final purpose or any number of arguments could change the grammar?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Well, I would say it's difficult to make a good plain example which completely simulates my originally intended scenarios. Every time I want to write a question to ask an English-related issue, I rack my brain to conceive a plain example to avoid a jargon-ridden text. But making an example which takes care of all points in my originally intended places is sometimes not easy. I have long unconsciously used this structure without suspecting if it's redundancy. When I start to suspect that, Jason Bassford does give an example wherein "...moreover ... also ..." isn't a redundancy.

Comment: In this case, were your “originally intended scenarios” to determine whether various synonyms used together constituted redundancy, or something else?

Why would it not suffice to ask “May I follow ‘moreover/further/furthermore/besides/additionally’ with ‘also’ or would that be a redundancy?”

Either way, your link https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/moreover doesn’t work for me. It leads to a simplistic definition nothing like your quotation “The university itself, moreover, is also unable to launch a serious defence of the proposed centre.” More…

Comment: Further… To put it more clearly, Jason Bassford is clearly mistaken. The *intention* appears to be as he states; the meaning is not.  “Also” is not only redundant but also unhelpful, let alone necessary. The meaning would indeed change without it, to become more clear.

The reason your ‘hometown’ example is so deplorable is simply that weeding out the pointless portions takes too much time and energy… thanks for the headaches!

If you cut that essay to something practical like “… moreover, the cost is also exorbitant…” does it not become clear?

Comment: Would you mind taking any more about this somewhere such as English Language Learners, where it might seem much more suited?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin There is no need to move there for further discussion if not many people are interested in discussing here. I have other far more meritorious questions to put there if I really want to fuss. I have said that I have unconsciously used this kind of emphasis for long, so maybe some cases look more redundant than others. The first example looks verbose because I deliberately add some unnecessary words to illustrate my issue, but it's not a text which I will actually put on some important document. If I can put my really intended text here, that would be more expressive.

Comment: Sorry, Captain Bohemian, and there remains the same need to move this somewhere such as English Language Learners as there’s always been: there, not here, is where it belongs. That’s most of the reason not many people are interested in discussing it here.

Please either explain in detail or better, forget about, how you had, or said you had unconsciously used this or anything for however long.

Within the apparent scope of your question, m there is no room for some cases to look more redundant than others, nor anything like that.

Comment: Still sorry, Captain Bohemian, and your first example doesn’t merely *appear*; it clearly *is* verbose for the simple reason you added irrelevant side issues which in no way helped to illustrate anything.

Please put here only something advanced enough to belong here, rather than, eg, at ELL and even then, please try harder to make it clear, than you have previously tried to make it “stylish” or “erudite” or “portentous.”

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If you like to argue the trivial so much, it's you who should go to ELL if you think ELL is for English language novices. Only novices or linguists would be care so much about the trivial of English language. I am neither a novice nor linguist, so I am only meticulous about the trivial of English language when writing on important documents. I think Jason Bassford has given an example sufficiently illustrating whether that's a redundancy in different situations. If you like to continue discussing this question on ELL, post a question with your own example there.

Comment: Sorry, Captain Bohemian, it’s not me but Stack Exchange that thinks ELL is for novices.

My reasons for supposing your Question belongs there are the Question itself, and the Comments you’ve made about everyone else’s responses.

If you think it’s my fault Jason was mistaken, or that you didn’t see that, please either explain how or accept Jason was mistaken. If that wasn’t true many people better qualified than any of us would have shot me down long ago.

Comment: Sorry, Captain; what you might mean by “novices or linguists” I’ve no idea. Are you lumping together all who do and don’t know and leaving out anyone else or what?

Can you translate “would be care so much about the trivial of…” into English or any known language, please?

Can you explain what anyone’s idea of “important” could change?

Sorry to say this again, and Jason Bassford gave an example of a *mistake* illustrating only his and your misunderstanding.

If you insist on perpetuating your misunderstanding please at least post some justification and preferably, an explanation.

Comment: Now I find another example in https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/besides, "Furthermore, besides food intake, other factors can also affect stool size.", wherein "besides" and "furthermore" and " also" are used together--two of my enumerated words are used with "also"!. This implies using these words together with "also" isn't necessarily a redundancy. In some situations I just feel obliged to add "also" even if I have used one of these words. This is probably further evidence that whether that's a redundancy depends on situations besides the example given by Jason Bassford.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot hit every aspect the OP raises but I will address "moreover" and "also" in the first segment he gives.

> My hometown is a deplorable place for it is so urbanized a concrete jungle that even access to a tiny piece of the natural scene therein is desperate, and moreover, the cost of living therein is also so exorbitant that one usually has to have a very highly paid job to reach decent material condition.

To simplify that

> My hometown is ugly for x, y, and z reasons, moreover, the cost is (also) more than most can afford.

"Moreover" could be replaced with 'and'  or 'and also' if you wanted.

> My hometown is ugly in this complex way, and (also) has high rent.

**But the problem with 'also' (where you have it) is NOT redundancy !**

The issue is your are signaling a second attribute to "cost" that is not there.

This would work:

> My hometown is ugly for complex reasons, moreover, the cost is hard to afford and also a bad value relative to other states.

So - not redundancy,  but a comparative word placed where there is nothing it is being compared to.

---

As for the Oxford Living Dictionaries

> The university itself, moreover, is also unable to launch a serious defence of the proposed centre.

@Jason_Bassford 's comment to another answer gives one way the sentence could work.

> The residents are unable to launch a serious defence of the proposed educational centre. The university itself, moreover, is also unable to launch a serious defence of the proposed centre.

I would admit that the word "itself"  and/or an omission of and object or party that the defense is being launched at boxes the "is also" into a mirror response.

Without 'itself' the university might be unable to do a few things in prior sentences.

If there were an object like "neighbors" then you could have Chemistry department is unable to convince it's faculty.  Moreover, the University has been unable to launch at defense for the center in the planning council meetings.

Comment: In the part of  your answer regarding my first example, should "and" be put prior to "moreover" as a conjunction?

Comment: I'm kind of a ways out mentally on this question and - don't want to sound too strident on grammar rules without confirmation of others.  I hope what I said helped. As for "and" whether or not that is strictly correct or not I think it is either Redundant OR will Sound Redundant to a large part of an audience.  We can't lose track of  the idea we write to ~communicate~ and if you lose part of your audience, it's kind of a moot point what is right.  In that spirit, I would suggest considering dropping "moreover" entirely - it is a bit stuffy or dated IMO.

Comment: I think that "also importantly" might be a more modern choice for you that hits my concern (whether it came through the way I said it or not) that moreover should accentuate the ramification of the prior issue rather than opening a new one.  "on top of that" , "if that wasn't enough", 'not only',  "surprisingly, despite those defects" just brainstorming for you.

Answer (score 0):

*Also* can be used in two ways: First, it can be used as a synonym of *moreover* and other words that mean “in addition,” as in, “Also, here is some more information.” Second, *also* can be used as a synonym of *too* or *likewise*, as in, “I also do not like summer.” Generally, the first usage will be in an introductory form; that is, at the beginning of a sentence or clause.

Answer (score 0):

**About synonyms**

First of all, note that "synonym" can have two meanings. Paraphrasing a dictionary definition, it can be either a word that's exactly the same or almost the same. This fact is sometimes ignored.

You asked the question:

> Should either "moreover" or "also" be removed?

with regard to the following examples:

> (simplified)
>   My town is bad because X and Y, and moreover, the cost of living
>   therein is also so exorbitant that...

and

> The university itself, moreover, is also unable to launch a serious
>   defence of the proposed centre.

and

> "Furthermore, besides food intake, other factors can also affect stool
>   size."

The definitions of "moreover" and "furthermore" tell us that they refer back to a previous thing said:

> moreover
>  in addition to what has already been said;
>   furthermore
>  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/moreover)

In the third example the sentence begins with "furthermore", so we have no idea of what has already been said. We can assume that it's a statement about food intake being a factor, but we don't exactly have this information.

However, "also" can be seen technically as a redundancy because you can remove it without changing it's meaning:

> Furthermore, besides food intake, other factors can <s>also</s>
>   affect stool size.

In the second example the only words before "moreover" are "The university itself", whose meaning is hard to identify exactly, probably because it isn't a complete sentence. Even if we replace "moreover" with "in addition", which is given as a synonym of "moreover", we need to know "in addition" to what? The "what" can't be "The university itself", because it's describing the "university itself" in some way in addition to something else, presumably said beforehand. So I'd say in the second and third examples we just don't have enough information with regard to "Furthermore" and "moreover".

In the case of your first example, we have more relevant information but suffers from a slight ambiguity in exact meaning. We have something basically like:

> My town is bad because X and Y, and moreover (in addition to that previously said), the cost of living therein is also so exorbitant that...

To be accurate, we don't know whether the word "moreover" (in addition to) refers to the town being said to be bad, or "X and Y" (the reasons why the town is bad). I believe before we make a judgement as to what is or isn't redundant we should know exactly what the heck the sentence is saying, and it's not entirely clear in all of the example sentences.

Instead I'll focus on a simplified example based on the university example:

> The university's partners are unable to fund it. The university itself, moreover, is also unable to fund it.

In this example you can make a case that "moreover" and "also" are mutually redundant. That is, you can remove "also" or "moreover" without having a change of meaning.

Now let's take another version:

> The university's partners are unable to fund it. There are many obstacles preventing progress and this is one of them. Moreover, the university itself is also unable to fund it.

Here one interpretation is that the "Moreover" means "in addition to the one obstacle preventing progress" and the "also" is including the university proper among the list of entities that are unable to fund it. They can refer to different things, and I would argue are not redundant with respect to each other necessarily. Of course you could argue "also" is redundant on a very pedantic basis, because:

John is sick. Mary is sick. All the rest are sick.
is equal to
John is sick. Mary is [also] sick. All the rest are sick.
 (also is not strictly needed)

Unless you REALLY wanted to get pedantic and say that by the time you read "Mary is sick" John has recuperated and is no longer sick. Haha.

So my opinion is that although in all your examples some redundant words seem to be used, it appears there isn't enough information or context, at least with two of your examples, to make this a certain evaluation.

**Should you avoid so-called redundancies or tautologies at all costs?**

I would argue there's a place for genuine redundancies, and that it's a stylistic choice. I would definitely use "and also" when just "and" would suffice. Here are examples of redundancies and what many consider to be redundancies:
**In law**

aid and abet (mean the same thing, exists for traditional reasons).

**In idiomatic language**

I fell / I fell down (would you fall up? OK this is a phrasal verb, but still, is it necessary?)
Above and beyond
free gift
tuna fish
safe haven
**More contentious ones (in my opinion):**

(close) proximity
(final) outcome

**In oratory:**

* we can not dedicate, we can not consecrate, we can not hallow, this ground.
(consecrate and hallow I'd argue are extremely close to being the same thing.)
* I have nothing to offer but blood, toil, tears and sweat. (Were these not metaphors, then they'd be different things. However being metaphors for sacrifice (or similar), then they all seem to mean the same thing in my opinion.

**In literature and poetry**

Only this and nothing more.

**Syntactic redundancies (or at least strictly unnecessary word addition):**

I entered (into) the room
I know (that) it's true

(Some of the above examples are taken from the [pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) Wikipedia article).

Comment: Nitpick, regarding *"aid and abet"*, this is not a redundancy - it means to assist and encourage, and although there are shades of each word in the other (a criminal may be implicitly encouraged by assistance, and may be assisted to complete the crime by receiving encouragement and so-called moral support), most people make a conceptual distinction between assistance and encouragement.

Comment: If 'synonyms' meant 'two or more words always having exactly the same meanings and always interchangeable in a string' I think the term would be unusable except as a fiction. // Here, the question is whether employing two synonyms adds a nuance neither single word evokes. In OP's first example, I'd certainly drop the 'also'. In the second example, there may be a previous set of comparisons licensing two additive connectors. May be.

Answer (score -1):

"Also" is redundant, which you can tell from the fact that its removal has no impact on the meaning of the sentence. Also, "so exorbitant" is redundant. You need "so" for the "so X that" construction, so replace the absolute "exorbitant" with the neutral "expensive".

Comment: No, that's not necessarily correct. It depends on the context. Consider a possible prior sentence to the second example: *The residents are unable to launch a serious defence of the proposed educational centre. The university itself, moreover, is* ***also*** *unable to launch a serious defence of the proposed centre.* The meaning here is that not only can the residents not support it, but the university (tasked with education specifically) cannot. The use of **also** is a necessary linkage—and the meaning would change with its absence.

Comment: Was your answer with respect to only the first example sentence? Or an answer to all uses?

Comment: In the "so ... that" construction, must the adjective following "so" a comparable one? And is "exorbitant" an absolute adjective? If that's the case, I didn't know these, so thank you for telling me these.

Comment: @JasonBassford You envisage a pretext I didn't think of. After reading this answer, I originally thought, based on the pretext I could imagine for the second example, removing either "moreover" or "also' doesn't affect the meaning of that sentence, either. But after reading your conceived pretext, I have to second-think. Probably whether "moreover" or "also" can be removed may really depend on the context. The example I make on my own is also just an illustration of a style which I often wish to use. I don't only want an answer to that example but an answer to general examples of that style.

Comment: @JasonBassford Excuse me, may I clarify a point with you? While I appreciate your addressing a possibility wherein using "moreover" and "also" together is not a redundancy, I don't quite agree that removing "also" would change the meaning of the sentence. I think all these words "moreover/..." and "also" are for emphasis rather than adding concrete meaning, and the reason that both "moreover" and "also" in the 2nd example are better not to be removed is that they refer to different things, whereas in my 1st example, either "moreover" or "also" can be removed for they refer to the same thing.